# How do I assign value when structure has a void *pointer

Tags: c

I am trying to assign a value to variable which has a **void *pointer**. Below is the assignment as best as I understand. (Doesn't work)

```
void set_fb_video ()
{

goldfish_lcd.dev.(atmel_lcdfb_info*)platform_data->default_monspecs->modedb->xres = 10;
};
```

Below are part of structures as defined in header files

**Header files**

```
struct fb_videomode {
      ..
      u32 xres;
      ..
};

struct fb_monspecs {
      ..
      struct fb_videomode *modedb;
      ..
};

struct atmel_lcdfb_info;

struct atmel_lcdfb_info {
      ..
      struct fb_monspecs *default_monspecs;
      ..
};

struct device {
     ..
     void *platform_data;
     ..
};

struct platform_device {
      ..
      struct device dev;
      ..
};
```

**C files**

```
struct fb_videomode at91_tft_vga_modes[] = {
      ..
      .xres = 100,
      ..
};


struct fb_monspecs &at91fb_default_monspecs = {
      ..
      .modedb = at91_tft_vga_modes,
      ..
};

struct atmel_lcdfb_info ek_lcdc_data = {
      ..
      .default_monspecs = &at91fb_default_monspecs,
      ..
};

struct platform_device goldfish_lcd ={
      ..
      .dev = {
           ..
           .platform_data = &ek_lcdc_data,
          },
      ..
};
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you writing in C or C++? You can't be writing in both, and the answer will be different in the two languages.

Comment: writing in C, I updated the tags

Comment: Thanks... In that case, I believe my answer should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cast isn't in the correct place, and you don't have a type called `atmel_lcdfb_info`:

```
((struct atmel_lcdfb_info*)goldfish_lcd.dev.platform_data)->default_monspecs->modedb->xres = 10;
```

Comment: @Jarod42 I can't tell if OP is writing in C or C++, since he's tagged the post with both. I wrote a comment asking him to clarify.